# Help socializing a 5-month old rescued feral street cat

Tags: cats, socializing, feral

Some kittens were born at the start of the year near my wife's workplace. One of her coworkers brings them cat food and rescued all kittens from the litter except one. He captured the remaining one for my wife on a transport box and we brought it home. Because we already have two other cats and haven't taken the rescued cat to the vet to check for diseases, we decided to place it in one of the bathrooms of our house so that we could take him/her to the vet on the next day.

However, after letting the cat out of the transport box, him/her is very scared and won't let us approach, making growling and hissing noises. He/she climbs to the higher spots of the bathroom (shower glass door and shower head), and only comes down to eat and use the litterbox when we're not there.

We left the transport box inside the bathroom. After a few days, I found him/her inside the transport box. He/she let me approach, but when I tried to close the transport box door, he/she quickly escaped and climbed to the shower head. Ever since, if he/she is inside the transport box, he/she will escape as soon as I step into the bathroom.

He/she was brought in two weeks ago, and while there have been some improvements in behavior -- I've caught him/her in the floor of the bathroom or on top of the (always closed) toilet bowl, but he/she still won't let us approach.

At this point we feel the cat is suffering, but we are simply unable to put him/her back inside the transport box, so we could at least take him/her to vet. Ideally we'd like to socialize and keep him/her, or at the very least take him/her to a shelter.

I'd like some suggestions of strategies to put the cat inside the transport box, and ideally to socialize him/her to stay with us.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Please have a look into the linked questions. It handles a very similar topic. If it does not helps you, please let us know! https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/31426/how-long-will-my-new-cat-stay-hidden